"UnsatisfiedDependencyException: Error creating bean with name 'eventService' defined in URL" when trying to deploy spring boot app on ubuntu
When I run the project on my development machine in IntelliJ IDEA, everything works perfectly without any errors, but as soon as I try to jar it and deploy it to my server running Ubuntu 24.04, I get this weird error:
Jun 01 20:16:31 raspberrypi5 AnimalShelter[36353]:   .   ____          _            __ _ _
Jun 01 20:16:31 raspberrypi5 AnimalShelter[36353]:  /\\ / ___'_ __ _ _(_)_ __  __ _ \ \ \ \
Jun 01 20:16:31 raspberrypi5 AnimalShelter[36353]: ( ( )\___ | '_ | '_| | '_ \/ _` | \ \ \ \
Jun 01 20:16:31 raspberrypi5 AnimalShelter[36353]:  \\/  ___)| |_)| | | | | || (_| |  ) ) ) )
Jun 01 20:16:31 raspberrypi5 AnimalShelter[36353]:   '  |____| .__|_| |_|_| |_\__, | / / / /
Jun 01 20:16:31 raspberrypi5 AnimalShelter[36353]:  =========|_|==============|___/=/_/_/_/
Jun 01 20:16:31 raspberrypi5 AnimalShelter[36353]:  :: Spring Boot ::                (v3.2.5)
Jun 01 20:16:31 raspberrypi5 AnimalShelter[36353]: 20:16:31.924 [main] INFO me.fazelukario.animalshelter.AnimalShelterApplication -- Starting AnimalShelterApplication using Java 22-ea with PID 36353 (/root/AnimalShelter/animalshelter.jar started by root in /root/AnimalShelter)
Jun 01 20:16:31 raspberrypi5 AnimalShelter[36353]: 20:16:31.930 [main] INFO me.fazelukario.animalshelter.AnimalShelterApplication -- No active profile set, falling back to 1 default profile: "default"
Jun 01 20:16:32 raspberrypi5 AnimalShelter[36353]: 20:16:32.479 [main] WARN org.springframework.context.annotation.AnnotationConfigApplicationContext -- Exception encountered during context initialization - cancelling refresh attempt: org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException: Error creating bean with name 'eventService' defined in URL [jar:file:/root/AnimalShelter/animalshelter.jar!/me/fazelukario/animalshelter/services/EventService.class]: Unsatisfied dependency expressed through constructor parameter 0: No qualifying bean of type 'me.fazelukario.animalshelter.repository.EventRepository' available: expected at least 1 bean which qualifies as autowire candidate. Dependency annotations: {}
Jun 01 20:16:32 raspberrypi5 AnimalShelter[36353]: 20:16:32.487 [main] ERROR org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication -- Application run failed
Jun 01 20:16:32 raspberrypi5 AnimalShelter[36353]: org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException: Error creating bean with name 'eventService' defined in URL [jar:file:/root/AnimalShelter/animalshelter.jar!/me/fazelukario/animalshelter/services/EventService.class]: Unsatisfied dependency expressed through constructor parameter 0: No qualifying bean of type 'me.fazelukario.animalshelter.repository.EventRepository' available: expected at least 1 bean which qualifies as autowire candidate. Dependency annotations: {}
Jun 01 20:16:32 raspberrypi5 AnimalShelter[36353]:         at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.createArgumentArray(ConstructorResolver.java:795)
Jun 01 20:16:32 raspberrypi5 AnimalShelter[36353]:         at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.autowireConstructor(ConstructorResolver.java:237)
Jun 01 20:16:32 raspberrypi5 AnimalShelter[36353]:         at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.autowireConstructor(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1355)
Jun 01 20:16:32 raspberrypi5 AnimalShelter[36353]:         at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBeanInstance(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1192)
Jun 01 20:16:32 raspberrypi5 AnimalShelter[36353]:         at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:562)
Jun 01 20:16:32 raspberrypi5 AnimalShelter[36353]:         at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:522)
Jun 01 20:16:32 raspberrypi5 AnimalShelter[36353]:         at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.lambda$doGetBean$0(AbstractBeanFactory.java:326)
Jun 01 20:16:32 raspberrypi5 AnimalShelter[36353]:         at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:234)
Jun 01 20:16:32 raspberrypi5 AnimalShelter[36353]:         at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:324)
Jun 01 20:16:32 raspberrypi5 AnimalShelter[36353]:         at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:200)
Jun 01 20:16:32 raspberrypi5 AnimalShelter[36353]:         at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.preInstantiateSingletons(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:975)
Jun 01 20:16:32 raspberrypi5 AnimalShelter[36353]:         at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishBeanFactoryInitialization(AbstractApplicationContext.java:962)
Jun 01 20:16:32 raspberrypi5 AnimalShelter[36353]:         at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:624)
Jun 01 20:16:32 raspberrypi5 AnimalShelter[36353]:         at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refresh(SpringApplication.java:754)
Jun 01 20:16:32 raspberrypi5 AnimalShelter[36353]:         at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refreshContext(SpringApplication.java:456)
Jun 01 20:16:32 raspberrypi5 AnimalShelter[36353]:         at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:334)
Jun 01 20:16:32 raspberrypi5 AnimalShelter[36353]:         at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1354)
Jun 01 20:16:32 raspberrypi5 AnimalShelter[36353]:         at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1343)
Jun 01 20:16:32 raspberrypi5 AnimalShelter[36353]:         at me.fazelukario.animalshelter.AnimalShelterApplication.main(AnimalShelterApplication.java:10)
Jun 01 20:16:32 raspberrypi5 AnimalShelter[36353]: Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.NoSuchBeanDefinitionException: No qualifying bean of type 'me.fazelukario.animalshelter.repository.EventRepository' available: expected at least 1 bean which qualifies as autowire candidate. Dependency annotations: {}
Jun 01 20:16:32 raspberrypi5 AnimalShelter[36353]:         at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.raiseNoMatchingBeanFound(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1880)
Jun 01 20:16:32 raspberrypi5 AnimalShelter[36353]:         at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.doResolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1406)
Jun 01 20:16:32 raspberrypi5 AnimalShelter[36353]:         at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.resolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1353)
Jun 01 20:16:32 raspberrypi5 AnimalShelter[36353]:         at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.resolveAutowiredArgument(ConstructorResolver.java:904)
Jun 01 20:16:32 raspberrypi5 AnimalShelter[36353]:         at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.createArgumentArray(ConstructorResolver.java:782)
Jun 01 20:16:32 raspberrypi5 AnimalShelter[36353]:         ... 18 common frames omitted

Here's code that mentioned in error (EventRepository):
@Repository
public interface EventRepository extends JpaRepository<Event, String> {
    @NonNull
    Optional<Event> findById(@NonNull String id);
}

Also part where it is autowiring (EventService):
@Service
@Slf4j
@Transactional(rollbackOn = Exception.class)
@AllArgsConstructor
public class EventService {
    @Autowired
    private EventRepository eventRepository;

I also get this error when I try to run the compiled jar on the same machine with the same jdk that I run it normally in IntelliJ.
The command I used is C:\Users\MyUser\.jdks\openjdk-22.0.1\bin\java.exe -jar .\animalshelter.jar

The command you used is not Ubuntu shell command, it is a command in Widows shell. Ubuntu is Linux, path delimiter in Linux file system is "/". Extension ".exe" is also from Windows world. First try in Ubuntu terminal java -version. If it does not work - install Java. If works try java -jar path_to_jar/you_application.jar If you use gradle look what you have in build/libs directory. Application jar should be there

The OP has apparently correctly used some linux command, since the jar is executed and Spring initialization is started. /root/AnimalShelter/animalshelter.jar started by root in /root/AnimalShelter Could you please post the exact commands though?

The command I mention in post belong to my statement "I also get this error when I try to run the compiled jar on the same machine with the same jdk that I run it normally in IntelliJ." which is obliviously windows machine.
Command I used on Linux is: /usr/bin/java -jar /root/AnimalShelter/animalshelter.jar
